# O binding dentro de um CompositeCollection não funciona

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou usando um ComboBox em uma aplicação WPF e quando uma função é ativada, essa carrega uma `List<string>` vinda de um webservice para uma propriedade na tela. Meu problema é que não consigo fazer com que o ComboBox atualize atualize quando essa propriedade é alterada (mesmo ela sendo do tipo `ObservableCollection<string>`. Ex:

**fragmento da tela**

```
...
<Button Content="teste" Click="carregaItens"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="cb">
  <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Gray" Content="selecione..."/>
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=itens}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
...
```

**fragmento da classe da tela**

```
public partial class Tela: Window
{
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<string> itens;
    private async void carregaItens(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itens = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        (await new WebService().getItens()).ForEach(x => itens.Add(x));
    }
    ...
}
```

**exemplo da classe webservice**

```
public class Webservice
{
    public async Task<List<string>> getItens()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => new List<string>(){ "foo", "bar", "bin" });
    }
}
```

Preciso que o `ComboBox` atualize seu conteúdo assim que a minha propriedade ìtens`seja atualizada mas que mantenha o primeiro`ComboBoxItem`, que serve como um valor inicial definido.

> **NOTA:** já encontrei diversos exemplos na internet que até me ajudaram a chegar até esse ponto mas nenhum deles demonstra como fazer o binding direto de uma propriedade na minha tela, todos eles me obrigam a ter uma Resource. um Model, ou algo do tipo, e quero fazer o binding direto.

Como resolver?

Comment: Qual o problema em usar um StaticResource que efectue o bind? Não tenho a certeza mas julgo que será a única forma.

Comment: Não há problema, mas a questão é que preciso usar múltiplas instancias do conteúdo e não vejo logica em trabalhar com N-StaticResource's... Afinal se é possível adicionar uma CompositeCollecion e juntar um combo padrão, deve ter uma forma de atualizar somente essa CollectionContainer

Comment: *"mas a questão é que preciso usar múltiplas instancias do conteúdo e não vejo logica em trabalhar com N-StaticResource's... "* - Coloque um exemplo na pergunta.

Comment: O **meu problema real** é que meu conteúdo do ComboBox não é estático e sim dinâmico, e além disso é Reativo, então se caso houver uma atualização no meu webservice, ele deve mudar as opções do ComboBox quando o usuário for re-selecionar.

Comment: Você está a fazer esse código na classe Tela(code behind) ou está a usar MVVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você [invoca que não pode usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286940/como-atualizar-um-combobox-a-partir-de-uma-observablecollection-property-da-wind#comment584476_286940) **StaticResource** porque o ComboBox é [dinâmico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286940/como-atualizar-um-combobox-a-partir-de-uma-observablecollection-property-da-wind#comment584871_286940). Tal facto em nada invalida o seu uso.

Para que o campo `itens` possa ser *"observable"* ele tem de ser uma propriedade.
Por outro lado, não deve criar uma nova instância mas sim alterar a existente.

Exemplo para testar:

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Itens { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    void CarregaItens(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Itens.Clear();
        GetItens().ForEach(x => Itens.Add(x));
    }

    //Simula o acesso ao sefvidor
    private static List<String> GetItens()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        return new List<string>
        {
            rand.Next(1, 10).ToString(),
            rand.Next(1, 10).ToString(),
            rand.Next(1, 10).ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="teste" Click="CarregaItens"/>

            <ComboBox x:Name="cb">
                <ComboBox.Resources>
                    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itens" Source="{Binding Itens}"/>
                </ComboBox.Resources>
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Gray" Content="selecione..."/>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource itens}}" />
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: realmente nessa forma ele funciona, mas eu sou obrigado a usar o `<ComboBox.Resources/>` para definir uma resource estática para o componente. Vou usar dessa forma mesmo, também não achei nenhuma forma mais simples de fazer isso. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro de tudo, uma das exigências do `binding` é a propriedade referenciada ser pública.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.

Nesse caso devemos corrigir a propriedade `itens` ficando assim:

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> itens;
```

**Sobre o `CompositeCollection`**

O problema está relacionado ao fato da classe [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) não ser derivada de um `FrameworkElement` e portanto ela não tem a propriedade `DataContext` para suportar `DataBinding`. Como podemos ver no `Console`

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

Não faz sentido essa classe ter esse tipo de problema. Pesquisando, parece que é um bug antigo e tem discussões sobre isso em 2008 ([como podemos ver aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b15cbd9d-95aa-47c6-8068-7ae9f7dca88a/collectioncontainer-does-not-support-relativesource?forum=wpf)).

(Fiz testes no .NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.1 e o bug ainda existe.)

Uma das soluções é utilizar um espécie de proxy ([citado nesse blog em 2011](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/))

Soluções:

**1 - Solução prática (partindo do que você já tem)**

Utilizar o `CollectionViewSource` (proxy xaml) para buscar os dados:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" >
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itens" Source="{Binding itens}"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Gray" Content="selecione..."/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource itens}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
```

**2 - Solução mais complicada (ideal para melhor qualidade)**

Criei um template para o `ComboBox` mantendo o estilo padrão (você pode customizar isso ao nível que deseja).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ExibeSelecione" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" IsEnabled="True" Foreground="Gray" Text="Selecione..."/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="ExibeSelecione"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Esse `TextBlock` é exibido toda vez que nenhum valor é selecionado

```
                <TextBlock x:Name="ExibeSelecione" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" IsEnabled="True" Foreground="Gray" Text="Selecione..."/>
```

Esse `Trigger` é responsável por identificar quando não há valor selecionado e exibir o `TextBlock`

```
 <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="ExibeSelecione"/>
  </Trigger>
```

-- Edit  --

@LeandroLuk A utilização do `Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource itens}}` não tem relação com a atualização de dados. Se você for definir um novo valor para propriedade `itens` como esta fazendo aqui

> ```
>     itens = new ObservableCollection<string>();
> ```

Então é necessário utilizar a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` para atualizar os dados na view. Ficando assim:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _itens;
    public ObservableCollection<string> itens { get { return _itens; } set { _itens = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private async void carregaItens(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itens = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        var result = await new WebService().getItens();
        result.ForEach(x => itens.Add(x));
    }
```

O resto é contigo... Espero que isso já ajude xD

Comment: FAN-TAS-TI-CO..